# App crashes if I extend FragmentActivity

Tags: android, google-maps, maps

I have been trying to extend FragmentActivity. The same app works if I extend the MainActivity class to Activity and import necessary packages for a normal Activity.

The basic need is that i cannot access the map in a normal activity. It needs to extend FragmentActivity to run the following line.

```
googleMap= ((SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
```

**Here is the Java code**

```
package com.dacoders.locationtodo;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

**Here is the layout XML**

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/map"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

**Here is the AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.dacoders.locationtodo"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
    <permission
        android:name="com.dacoders.locationtodo.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.dacoders.locationtodo.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
        <!-- The following two permissions are not required to use
             Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended. -->
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

        <uses-feature
                android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
                android:required="true"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.dacoders.locationtodo.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
    android:value="API_KEY_HERE"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**Here is the LOG**

```
0622 21:01:25.911: D/dalvikvm(13621): Lateenabling CheckJNI
 0622 21:01:25.991: D/AndroidRuntime(13621): Shutting down VM
 0622 21:01:25.991: W/dalvikvm(13621): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41629930)
 0622 21:01:26.001: E/AndroidRuntime(13621): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 0622 21:01:26.001: E/AndroidRuntime(13621): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.dacoders.locationtodo/com.dacoders.locationtodo.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment
 0622 21:01:26.001: E/AndroidRuntime(13621):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
 0622 21:01:26.001: E/AndroidRuntime(13621):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
 0622 21:01:26.001: E/AndroidRuntime(13621):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
 0622 21:01:26.001: E/AndroidRuntime(13621):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
 0622 21:01:26.001: E/AndroidRuntime(13621):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
 0622 21:01:26.001: E/AndroidRuntime(13621):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
 0622 21:01:26.001: E/AndroidRuntime(13621):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
 0622 21:01:26.001: E/AndroidRuntime(13621):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 0622 21:01:26.001: E/AndroidRuntime(13621):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
 0622 21:01:26.001: E/AndroidRuntime(13621):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
 0622 21:01:26.001: E/AndroidRuntime(13621):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
 0622 21:01:26.001: E/AndroidRuntime(13621):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 0622 21:01:26.001: E/AndroidRuntime(13621): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment
 0622 21:01:26.001: E/AndroidRuntime(13621):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
 0622 21:01:26.001: E/AndroidRuntime(13621):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)
 0622 21:01:26.001: E/AndroidRuntime(13621):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
 0622 21:01:26.001: E/AndroidRuntime(13621):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
 0622 21:01:26.001: E/AndroidRuntime(13621):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:270)
 0622 21:01:26.001: E/AndroidRuntime(13621):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1881)
 0622 21:01:26.001: E/AndroidRuntime(13621):    at com.dacoders.locationtodo.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:12)
 0622 21:01:26.001: E/AndroidRuntime(13621):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
 0622 21:01:26.001: E/AndroidRuntime(13621):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
 0622 21:01:26.001: E/AndroidRuntime(13621):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
 0622 21:01:26.001: E/AndroidRuntime(13621):    ... 11 more
 0622 21:01:26.001: E/AndroidRuntime(13621): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment cannot be cast to android.support.v4.app.Fragment
 0622 21:01:26.001: E/AndroidRuntime(13621):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:394)
 0622 21:01:26.001: E/AndroidRuntime(13621):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:369)
 0622 21:01:26.001: E/AndroidRuntime(13621):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:272)
 0622 21:01:26.001: E/AndroidRuntime(13621):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:676)
 0622 21:01:26.001: E/AndroidRuntime(13621):    ... 20 more
```

Comment: The app crashes in the above case.

Comment: Your android:minSdkVersion is 11.  You don't need FragmentActivity, just use Activity.  According to http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html:
  "Base class for activities that want to use the support-based Fragment and Loader APIs."

  You don't need the support library in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Your min sdk is 11.  I guess you can make it 12 and use `MapFragment`.

To know why check the link http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html.

In that case (minsdk is 12 or above) you can extend `Activity`

```
  GoogleMap mMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                                .getMap();
```

Also import

```
  import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;

                   Or
```

You should use `Support Fragment`.

```
<fragment
class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
android:id="@+id/map"  
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Your activity must extend `FragmentActivity`

```
SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment)  getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
GoogleMap mMap = fm.getMap();
```

Make sure you have added support library

Also make sure you imported the below

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;  
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
```

Comment: Turns out, I just had to keep the fragment inside a linear/relative layout. Thanks anyways

Comment: @user2361490 In any case if your min sdk is below 12 you should use `SupportFrament`. check the link https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapFragment. check the line just above Developer Guide heading

Comment: @user2361490 and if you use `MapFragment` you can extend a normal standard `Activity`. so either change your min sdk to 12 in that case or use `SupportFragment` as suggested.

Answer (score 0):

> Here is the layout XML
>
> `<fragment`

I'm not sure if you can have a fragment as the root of your layout as fragments are supposed to be pieces that are put in another layout and exchanged.

Have you tried putting your fragment in a FrameLayout and see if it still crashes?

Comment: "Turns out, I just had to keep the fragment inside a linear/relative layout. Thanks anyways". I guess I should have refreshed before posting.